# Ansible not recognising variables not found under host_vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ι have the following inventory

```
[foo]
foosrv ansible_host=11.22.33.44 

[bar]
barsrv ansible_host=44.11.22.33

[zoo]
zoosrv ansible_host=21.21.21.21
```

and the following file structure

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── files
│   └── aws.yaml
├── host_vars
│   ├── foosrv
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── repoConf.yaml.j2
│   │   └── vault
│   └── barsrv
│       ├── templates
│       │   └── repoConf.yaml.j2
│       └── vault
├── inventory
├── site.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── amend.py.j2
│   └── config.j2
└── vars
    ├── ansible_vars.yaml
    └── vault
```

My problem is that any variables under `./vars/vault` are not recognized by `ansible`.

Any hints about what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ansible doesn't automatically load variables from a `vars` directory.

You have several options for loading variables:

- Ansible will load variables from a file (or directory) in `host_vars` matching the inventory hostname.
- Ansible will load variables from a file (or directory) in `group_vars` matching the names of groups of which a host is a member.
- You can use the `include_vars` task to explicitly load variables from a file.

If you want to load the variables for all hosts automatically, then place them in `group_vars/all.yaml` (or a subdirectory of `group_vars/all`).

Ansible will automatically detect (and decrypt, if you've provided a password) files that are vault encrypted.

Comment: does `host_vars/all` (directory) or `host_vars/all.yaml` (file) serve for common variables across all hosts?

Comment: No, because that's exactly what `group_vars/all` is for.